# How to convert a heavily nested dynamic json to a editable table in WPF form using C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I am wondering if there is a simple and best way to convert a heavily nested json into a editable tables on a WPF form where the user can edit the table. After editing is done i want to convert the edited table back to json again. I am new to C# . I would really appreciate any suggestion on how to achieve this.

PS: The json is dynamic (new keys can be added or deleted and the structure might change).

Comment: use [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert raw JSON into your own classes

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but the json is dynamic. my bad i should have mentioned it before. btw i have updated the question.

Comment: @DeLorean IMO you will need to write your own JsonConverter to parse the json based on the rules of how the structure might change

Comment: @SirRufo, i meant WPF not WinForms.

Comment: Bit open ended. Try posting on [softwarerecs.se] might have better luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward:

- use types from `System.Text.Json` as the model
- build a view model to wrap it (There is 3 main type: `JsonArray`, `JsonObject` and `JsonValue` all are derived from `JsonNode`)
- to make it works fine with a `TreeView` and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, the view model must also know the *key* matching the `JsonNode`.
  The key can be *root*, an object property name, an array element index

This is a first draft for a read-only version.
The code is available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/4eff1749/SO_75798029).

[image: A screenshot of the application]

### The keys:

```csharp
public enum JsonKeyType
{
    Root,
    Index,
    Parameter
}

public abstract class JsonKey
{
    public abstract JsonKeyType KeyType { get; }
}

public class IndexKey : JsonKey
{
    public IndexKey(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
    }

    public int Index { get; }

    public override JsonKeyType KeyType => JsonKeyType.Index;

    public override string ToString() => $"@{Index}";
}

public class PropertyKey : JsonKey
{
    public PropertyKey(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; }

    public override JsonKeyType KeyType => JsonKeyType.Parameter;

    public override string ToString() => Key;
}

public class RootKey : JsonKey
{
    public static RootKey Instance { get; } = new();

    private RootKey()
    {
    }

    public override JsonKeyType KeyType => JsonKeyType.Root;

    public override string ToString() => "Root";
}
```

### The view models:

```csharp
public abstract class JsonViewModel
{
    public static JsonViewModel? From(JsonKey key, JsonNode? jsonNode)
    {
        return jsonNode switch
        {
            JsonArray jsonArray => new JsonArrayViewModel(key, jsonArray),
            JsonObject jsonObject => new JsonObjectViewModel(key, jsonObject),
            JsonValue jsonValue => new JsonValueViewModel(key, jsonValue),
            null => new JsonValueViewModel(key, null),
            _ => throw new UnreachableException()
        };
    }

    protected JsonViewModel(JsonKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public JsonKey Key { get; }
}

public class JsonArrayViewModel : JsonViewModel
{
    private readonly JsonArray _jsonArray;

    public JsonArrayViewModel(JsonKey key, JsonArray jsonArray) : base(key)
    {
        _jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }

    public IEnumerable<JsonViewModel?> Values => _jsonArray.Select((node, index) => From(new IndexKey(index), node));
}

public class JsonObjectViewModel : JsonViewModel
{
    private readonly JsonObject _jsonObject;

    public JsonObjectViewModel(JsonKey key, JsonObject jsonObject) : base(key)
    {
        _jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }

    public IEnumerable<JsonViewModel?> Values => _jsonObject.Select(kvp => From(new PropertyKey(kvp.Key), kvp.Value));
}

public class JsonValueViewModel : JsonViewModel
{
    public JsonValueViewModel(JsonKey key, JsonValue? jsonValue) : base(key)
    {
        if (jsonValue is null)
        {
            Value = "null";
            ValueKind = JsonValueKind.Null;
        }
        else
        {
            var jsonElement = jsonValue.GetValue<JsonElement>();

            Value = jsonElement.GetRawText();
            ValueKind = jsonElement.ValueKind;
        }
    }

    public string Value { get; }

    public JsonValueKind ValueKind { get; }
}
```

### The view:

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:JsonArrayViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Gray" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:JsonObjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Gray" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:JsonValueViewModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        ToolTip="{Binding ValueKind}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, StringFormat='{}{0}: '}" Foreground="Gray">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key.KeyType}" Value="{x:Static local:JsonKeyType.Index}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```